# How to capture STDOUT from executable (cap) executed within a perl script executed from a crontab

Tags: perl, bash, shell, cron, capistrano

Whew that is a long-winded title.  But it explains my issue:

I have a crontab that runs a perl script.

That perl script runs a cap task, which outputs to STDOUT some status messages.

The perl script is supposed to capture the STDOUT (currently using backticks) from cap and parse it.

Now, this works 100% fine when I run the script from a bash user.  However, when I run the script from a crontab, the perl script doesn't capture any output from the cap task.

Has anyone dealt with anything like this before?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that perl is running in the crontab? Often it will use a different environment from cron and lose the perl exe or some of the perl lib settings

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I actually am sure that perl is running in the crontab.  My log file gets created, all the same lines get written...  Only instead of $check_result = 'results to parse', it prints $check_result = ''

Comment: How are you running the `cap` task? You might be getting more error messages in STDERR. See this to get STDERR in cron http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308484/cron-job-stderr-to-email-and-log-file

Comment: Backticks work perfectly fine from a cron job. You have yet to identify a crucial factor.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean I have yet to identify a crucial factor?

Comment: Anyways, I still haven't found a solution for this.  There is some weird interactions going on between capistrano, perl, and crontab that I haven't quite figured out.  I decided to just cut the cap task out of the loop, and things are working again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your cap executables are died without emitting any message to stdout. Did you checking the success state of execution?

Could you tried this?

```
$check_result = `$cmd 2>&1`;
if ($?){
  die "$cmd failed with $check_result, $!";    
}
```